# conceptual questions about version control

Tags: git, version-control

I've only just started to use version control tools in a non-trivial way, and I'd like to have some iffy bits cleared out.

1. What counts as a conflict, and how does a version control tool resolve one?
2. Do two people working independently on one project always work on two different branches? Is the merging of branches automatic, assuming there isn't any conflict?

Thanks

Comment: Answers to general questions like these are covered fairly well in this guide to Git (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What counts as a conflict, and how does a version control tool resolve one?

A conflict occurs when a merge operation would mean applying two distinct changes to the same section of a file.  This can happen if two people have independently been editing a file and attempt to sync their repositories, or if you make conflicting changes in two separate local branches and attempt to merge them together.

Version control tools can resolve a conflict automatically by applying some sort of user-specified rule, such as:

- Most recent edit wins,
- Local edits win,
- Remote edits win,
- etc.

But the default behavior of most version control systems is to simply flag conflicts to be resolved manually.

> Do two people working independently on one project always work on two different branches?

Not necessarily, no, although it can certainly make sense to do so, especially if they are working on thematically different aspects of the project.

> Is the merging of branches automatic, assuming there isn't any conflict?

You have to tell your version control system to perform a merge operation, but
generally yes, your version control system should be able to automatically complete the merge non-conflicting edits.